# Highlight the first item in the tilelist in flex

Tags: apache-flex, tilelist

I am navigating the items of tile list using next and previous button. I need to highlight the first item in the tilelist by default ( like the first item is being selected by default)

Answer (score 1):

Just require selection, which will default select the first item:

```
<s:List requireSelection="true">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Otherwise, you can set the selected index:

```
<s:List selectedIndex="0" />
```

Or...

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function selectFirstItem():void
        {
            list.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:List id="list" />
```

Likewise if you're using the deprecated mx:TileList

```
<mx:TileList selectedIndex="0" />
```

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for the reply. But what I wanted is the highlight/Selection color(default blue) needs to be shown without mouseover

Comment: Im still not sure what your question really is. I get confused by your "selected" and "mouseover".

Comment: The first item of the tile list should be shown highlighted/Selected by default